# Automatically Open URL in an iframe (XSL)

Tags: html, xslt, iframe

I am using XSL to create a specific URL for different variables based on the values in an Excel sheet. I have everything working expect I currently have to click the link created to open the URL in the iframe. I was hoping I could accomplish this without a click so the link would load when the page was opened. Here is the relevant piece of code:

```
<xsl:when test="FieldName[starts-with(., 'UniqueID')]">
 <b>
  <a target="IFRAME">
   <xsl:attribute name="href">
    file:///C:/Users/me/documents/<xsl:value-of select="FieldValue"/>.html
   </xsl:attribute>
  <xsl:value-of select="FieldValue"/>
  </a>
 </b>
</xsl:when>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create directly the iframe:

```
<xsl:when test="FieldName[starts-with(., 'UniqueID')]">
  <iframe>
    <xsl:attribute name="src">
      file:///C:/Users/me/documents/<xsl:value-of select="FieldValue"/>.html
    </xsl:attribute>
  </iframe>
</xsl:when>
```